# Pandas Dataframe but does not display filtered results. Filter Logic works, display shows NaT for filtered results

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I am trying to simply filter based on the date in the Date_Start column and return a dataframe that includes the index, Full_Path and Date_Start columns.  Seems like all examples I have found do not return the NaN and NaT I am receiving as seen below.  On Pandas .22 and Python 2.7.13.

```
In: FilesFrame
Out:
     Full_Path                                 Date_Start
0    \\file_path\file2018-02-12_20-47-01.txt   2018-02-12 20:47:01 
1    \\file_path\file2018-02-12_20-47-01.txt   2018-02-12 20:47:01
2    \\file_path\file2018-02-12_20-47-01.txt   2018-02-12 20:47:01
3    \\file_path\file2018-02-15_20-47-05.txt   2018-02-15 20:47:05

In[2]:  start_date = '2018-02-15 20:47:05'
In[3]:  condition1 = FilesFrame['Date_Start'] == start_date
In[4]:  FilesFrame[(condition1)]
Out[4]:
     Full_Path                                 Date_Start
0    NaN                                       NaT 
1    NaN                                       NaT
2    NaN                                       NaT
3    NaN                                       2018-02-15 20:47:05
```

Desired result:

```
     Full_Path  
3    \\file_path\file2018-02-15_20-47-05.txt   2018-02-15 20:47:05
```

Additional Information:

```
In[5]: FilesFrame.dtypes
Out[5]:
Full_Path     object
Date_Start    datetime64[ns]
```

Comment: remove `()` like `FilesFrame[condition1]`

Comment: I cannot reproduce this. `FilesFrame[(condition1)]` gives me the desired result. Are you sure you are checking against a column instead of a set of columns? This would happen if your condition is a DataFrame of bool values instead of a Series.

Comment: You are probably doing something like `condition1 = FilesFrame == start_date` or `condition1 = FilesFrame[['Date_Start']] == start_date`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to ayhan for testing and taking a guess.  It turned out that when I assigned the 'Full_Path' column I added it like this:

```
FilesFrame.columns = [['Full_Path']]
```

Instead of:

```
FilesFrame.columns = ['Full_Path']
```

This was similar to his suggestion and resolves this issue.